# How to check multidimensional array of arrays contains array?

Tags: postgresql, array

I have an array of arrays [ID, TYPE].

All values are integer. Array can be `integer[]` or `jsonb` type.

```
SELECT array[[442,2],[443,2]]

SELECT to_jsonb(array[[1,2],[3,4]])
```

How can I check this array(s) contains array [443,2]?

**EDIT**
One of the way to check described here.

```
1# SELECT array[[442,2],[443,2]] @> array[443,2] -- returns True
2# SELECT array[[442,2],[443,2]] @> array[2,443] -- returns True too
```

For my case, I want get False in `2#`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically there is no such thing as a two-dimensional array in Postgres. [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html):

> *The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of dimensions either. [...] So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in CREATE TABLE is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time behavior*

So the value `array[[442,2],[443,2]]` is internally stored as `array[442,2,443,2]` and that's the reason why `array[[442,2],[443,2]] @> array[2,443]` is true, because it is internally represented as `array[442,2,443,2] @> array[2,443]` which obviously is true.

You can however do that if you declare an array of a row type.

```
create type idtype as (id integer, type integer);
```

Then you can do the following:

```
select array[(442,2), (443,2)]::idtype[] @> array[(442,2)]::idtype[];
--> true
```

but

```
select array[(442,2), (443,2)]::idtype[] @> array[(2,442)]::idtype[];
--> false
```

Answer (score 1):

## Potential Workaround with JSONB

As a potential workaround to PostgreSQL not respecting dimensionality, you can use JSONB. As a caveat though the containment operator (`@>`) isn't looking for a match based on an "array". It's decomposing the array and looking for a match on the elements. So these return true

```
SELECT '[[4,5]]'::jsonb @> '[[5,4]]';
SELECT '[[4,3,5]]'::jsonb @> '[[5,4]]';
SELECT '[[1,2],[4,3,5],[0]]'::jsonb @> '[[5,4]]';
```

but this returns false,

```
SELECT '[[1,2],[4,3,5],[0]]'::jsonb @> '[[5,0]]';
```